# Capturing 0-n occurrences of a regex group

Tags: python, regex-group

I'm parsing output from textfiles that could change depending on when script is executed. I want to capture one or more lines of ip address, advertised address, and age. When I run my script it only captures the first or last match depending on where I place the metacharacters, however I want all the ip lines to be captured. The amount of ip lines can change depending on time of day. The rest remains the same.

[image: Text]

when I run this code the "link" capture group only captures the first or last ip line, after  each "Link States" headers and column headers as a match~ it's capturing "link_state" match group just fine, and everything else is ok, however not capturing all of the ip lines ~ any suggestions on capturing them all as a group (i've included my IDLE output at the end)?

```
import re

temp = []
infile = ["ospf_r4.txt", "ospf_r1.txt"]


regex = (
    r"(?P<link_state>[\S+ ]* +Link States) ?(?:\(Area \S+\))?\n"
    r"\n*"
    r"(?P<link_col>Link ID) +(?P<adv_col>ADV Router) +(?P<age_col>Age) +Seq# +(?:[\S+ ]?)+"
    r"\n*"
    r"**(**(?P<link>[\d+\.]+ +[\d+\.]+ +[\d]+**)**+ +[\S+ *]*[\n]*)+"

        )
         


def temp_function(infile):
    global temp
    temp = []
    with open(infile, "r") as x:
        c = x.read()
        result = re.finditer(regex, c)
        for i in result:
            #temp.append(i.group())
            #print(i.group("link"))
            print(i)
        return temp
```

here is my output from IDLE, note instead of 8 ip's it gives me 5. Moving between finditer or findall has not worked for me. Any suggestions?

4.4.4.4       4.4.4.4  1993

172.16.14.2   4.4.4.4  1993

192.168.2.0   1.1.1.1  1031

3.3.3.3       1.1.1.1  1031

10.0.0.0      3.3.3.3  977

Comment: [Please post textual data directly instead of using screenshots.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Won't findall with this simpler regex do the job ?  myreg = r'[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+[^\w]+[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+[^\w]+[0-9]+'

Answer (score 0):

well I found one way of doing this

```
regex = (
r"[\S+\- ]* +Link States ?[\(Area \S+\)]*\n"
r"\n*"
r"(Link ID +ADV Router +Age) +Seq# +[\S+ ]*"
r"\n*"
r"(?:([\d+\.]+ +[\d+\.]+ +[\d+]+)?) *\S+ *\S+ *\S*\n*"
r"(?:([\d+\.]+ +[\d+\.]+ +[\d+]+)? +\S+ +\S+ *[\d+]*\n)?"
r"(?:([\d+\.]+ +[\d+\.]+ +[\d+]+)? +\S+ +\S+ *[\d+]*\n)?"
r"(?:([\d+\.]+ +[\d+\.]+ +[\d+]+)? +\S+ +\S+ *[\d+]*\n)?"
r"(?:([\d+\.]+ +[\d+\.]+ +[\d+]+)? +\S+ +\S+ *[\d+]*\n)?"
r"(?:([\d+\.]+ +[\d+\.]+ +[\d+]+)? +\S+ +\S+ *[\d+]*\n)?"
r"(?:([\d+\.]+ +[\d+\.]+ +[\d+]+)? +\S+ +\S+ *[\d+]*\n)?"
    )
```

I am wondering if there's a way to nest the regex into a single line, and to match on 1 or more matches?   I'm trying to avoid a match of "None" if the match doesn't exist

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).